# Zero Inflated Negative Binomial not producing standard errors - R

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

I've recently learned about using ZI-Negative Binomial in R, but I haven't been able to figure out why my model results are not calculating a standard error.

```
fit.zinb<-zeroinfl(comp_counts~bc,dist="negbin",link="logit",data=master_region)
summary(fit.zinb)
```

Output:

```
Call:
zeroinfl(formula = comp_counts ~ bc, data = master_region, dist = "negbin", link = "logit")

Pearson residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
 -0.2402  -0.2385  -0.2385  -0.2385 461.0861 

Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  3.534e-01         NA      NA       NA
bc           2.301e-09         NA      NA       NA
Log(theta)  -2.826e+00         NA      NA       NA

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -12.95553         NA      NA       NA
bc           -0.00567         NA      NA       NA

Theta = 0.0593 
Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 48 
Log-likelihood: -3.431e+05 on 5 Df
```

The dependent variable `comp_counts` is indeed inflated with 0's (83% of observations for the dependent variable are actually 0's).

To provide additional details on the variables, `comp_counts` is a count, ranging from 0 to 2754, and `bc` is a continuous variable. However, the independent variable `bc` also has several 0's (99.4% of observations are 0). Could this be causing the problem in the model?

Thanks for your help! Apologies for the novice question. Happy to provide the data if it is helpful.

*Edit*: the same issue (no standard errors) also occurs when I use the zero inflated poisson model. No warnings are produced, so not sure what's happening

*Edit 2*: Performing the regression models by reversing the dependent and independent variable does produce results with standard errors (ie, the dependent is now `bc` and independent `comp_counts`). But this is not the direction of causality that I seek to explore

```
Call:
zeroinfl(formula = bc ~ comp_counts, data = master_region, dist = "poisson", link = "logit")

Pearson residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
  -0.09871   -0.07143   -0.07143   -0.07143 4732.55835 

Count model coefficients (poisson with log link):
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 1.321e+01  3.179e-05  415741   <2e-16 ***
comp_counts 7.672e-03  3.626e-06    2116   <2e-16 ***

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  5.2781149  0.0232286 227.224   <2e-16 ***
comp_counts -0.0002349  0.0010703  -0.219    0.826    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

*EDIT 3*: The data is attached [here](https://github.com/smartkidyn/zeroinflation/blob/main/master_region.xlsx)

Comment: Please provide data. I suspect numerical problems driven by *complete separation* in your zeros component. (FWIW this looks more suited to Stack Overflow than CrossValidated, but it would be hard to know that in advance ...)

Comment: Ahh I was hoping it wouldn't be complete separation. I've uploaded the data to github! Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find good resources on how to grapple with complete separation in zero-inflation models

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always a good idea to plot the data first (especially if like me you're *not* familiar with it): I like `ggplot` for its flexibility, but it doesn't really matter what tool you use. I arrived at this after a few iterations:

```r
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
(ggplot(master_region,aes(bc,comp_counts)) 
    ## show overlapping/replicated points as circles (semi-transparent)
    + stat_sum(alpha=0.5) 
    ## cosmetic: make minimum size (non-replicated) points larger             
    + scale_size(range=c(2,8))
    ## put both x- and y-axes on a log(1+x) scale
    + scale_x_continuous(trans="log1p")
    + scale_y_continuous(trans="log1p")
    ## fit and display a flexible smooth curve for point data, **not** 
    ## including points at x=0
    + geom_smooth(data=subset(master_region,bc>0),
                  method="gam",method.args=list(family="quasipoisson"))
)
```

[image: scatterplot of data on log(1+x)/log(1+x) scales]

Additionally, `with(master_region,table(bc=bc>0, cc=comp_counts>0))` gives:

```
       cc
bc       FALSE   TRUE
  FALSE 302109  64678
  TRUE    1420    452
```

So far we know:

- most of your data fall at `bc==0`, `comp_counts==0`
- the data with `bc==0, comp_counts>0` have an extremely wide range in `comp_counts` (0-2754)
- the data have an extremely wide range in `bc` (0-1.84e8), although the range of `comp_counts` is narrower for `bc>0` (only up to 108)

This is going to be extremely challenging to fit from a computational standpoint. The problems with your standard deviations stem ultimately from the fact that R is having trouble computing the *Hessian*, i.e. the matrix that describes the curvature of the log-likelihood surface at the estimated parameter values.

One very simple solution is to scale your predictor variable: this sets the mean of the predictor to 0 and the SD to 1, which generally improves performance.

```r
fit.zinb0 <- zeroinfl(comp_counts~scale(bc),dist="negbin",link="logit",
                     data=master_region)
```

You'll have to back-scale your parameters if you want to know the values on the original scale (i.e. multiply the `bc` coefficient by `sd(bc)` ... you can also back-transform the intercept, I'm too lazy to post this at the moment).  But everything else about the model (Z-scores/p-values of predictors, overall goodness of fit, predictions, etc.) will be unchanged.

Alternately, you could consider fitting on the `log(1+bc)` scale:

```r
fit.zinb <- zeroinfl(comp_counts~log10(1+bc),dist="negbin",link="logit",
                     data=master_region)
```

Finally, independently of these I would consider whether you want to model the behaviour at `bc==0` separately from the behaviour for `bc>0`.

Comment: Wow, thank you for this thoughtful answer! These workarounds make sense to me. And apologies for posting on Stack, misinterpreted the comment about where this post belonged.